# Loading JSON data and binding it to an array within an model and then display the array elements?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know the correct way of doing this task, I have a JSON file which has alphabets from A to Z. I would like to load the file within my app and assigned the loaded data to an array called "alphabets" within a model called "dObj" and then display all the elements of the array using {{#each}} loop.

I am uncertain about how to bind the data to the model. Within ArrayController's pushObject() method, I am passing the create() method whereas I should not only be creating the object, but also be pushing the load data to the array within the model.

I appreciate all your help. Thank you.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/Y3dcs/

CODE:

```
    $function(){

        App = Ember.Application.create();

        App.dObj = Ember.Object.extend({
            alphabets: []
        });

        App.DObjController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
            content: [],
            loadAlphabets: function(){
                var self = this;
                $.getJSON('data/alphabets.json', function(data){
                    data.forEach(function(item){
                        self.pushObject(App.dObj.create(item));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        App.initialize();
    });
```

JSON FILE

```
{
    'alphabets' : [
                    'A','B''C','D','E','F','G',
                    'H','I','J','K','L','M','N',
                    'O','P','Q','R','S','T','U',
                    'V','W','X','Y','Z'
                    ]
}
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.Button target="App.DObjController" action="loadAlphabets"}}
       Load Alphabets
    {{/view}}

    {{#each App.DObjController}}
        {{alphabets}}                          
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: -1 for posting a fiddle that has numerous syntactic errors. And it is rather unuseful to discuss a fiddle that involves a $.getJSON that cannot work properly in a fiddle, since no one has a server running delivering your json example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3dcs/2/
I fixed the syntactic errors in this version.

Comment: Don't be offended. Downvoting questions is thought to mark questions that are badly researched. Even the alert in your did not get called. And actually you did implicitly ask for someone writing your code with thatbad fiddl.

Comment: I am not offended am merely pointing out what I was in search of. Thanks to C4P, here is one of the solutions: 
"What you want to do is create a new dObj for each letter returned by your ajax call, and then push those objects into the DObjController ArrayController"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a new `dObj` for each letter returned by your ajax call, and then push those objects into the `DObjController` ArrayController.

Then, to display this array of objects you need to use the `{{#each letterObj in App.DObjController}}` template helper command to loop through each of the `dObj` instances containing your letter data and output the stored letter data.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/Y3dcs/8/)

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.Button target="App.DObjController" action="loadAlphabets"}}
       Load Alphabets
    {{/view}}

    {{#each letterObj in App.DObjController}}
        {{letterObj.letter}}                          
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    App = Ember.Application.create({
        ready: function(){
            alert('APP INIT');
}
    });

    App.dObj = Ember.Object.extend({
    });

    App.DObjController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [],
        loadAlphabets: function(){
            var self = this;
            //$.getJSON('data/alphabets.json', function(data){
            //    data.forEach(function(item){
            //        self.pushObject(App.dObj.create(item));
            //    });
            //});

            setTimeout(function() {
                var alphabets = [
                    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G",
                    "H","I","J","K","L","M","N",
                    "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U",
                    "V","W","X","Y","Z"
                    ];
                alphabets.forEach(function(item){
                    self.pushObject(App.dObj.create({letter:item}));
                });
            },1000);
        }
    });
    App.initialize();
});​
```

Comment: Thank you so much C4P, I really appreciate all your help, this is wonderful.